# Background color of tabbar and alert messages are bright yellow after xcode update

Tags: xcode, background

I updated my xcode to 12.3 and it changed the background colors to bright yellow on Navigation Tab bar and alertviews.

I have them set to default colors and that appears to be light grey.  The text and images remain black but I noticed that one of the images has gone to full color.  Very weird.

Also the background color of the entire simulator, even the App Settings page, has turned bright yellow.  I can change colors in the inspector panel (though the text tint does not change, always white) and it changes it on the xib screen but the simulator still shows the bright yellow background with the correct blue if selected and dark gray if not selected images and text.

The change effected every tab bar in the app.  When run on actual device, the colors are normal.  Translucent is checked.  When unchecked the background color appears white.

Anyone give me advice on what to do here?

[image: Screenshot of xib editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacOS had an update and after I installed that, the colors reverted to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after install xcode 12.3. This is how to fix the issue.
Certain parts of the screen appear yellow in Interface Builder and the simulator.

First do this...
Open your Simulator and go to File > GPU Selection > Prefer Integrated GPU in

Then do this...
Quit Xcode and simulator
Unplug power cable
Restart Xcode and simulator
Check storyboard or simulator to confirm yellow tint is gone
Reconnect in power cable

Worked for me. Good luck

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  I was a little confused by your instructions to unplug power cord.  Do you meet unplug the computer after quiting xcode or do you mean the usb cord to the actual device that I am running through xcode?

Comment: Unplug the power cable from your mac. 
Restart your Mac. Launch Xcode. Confirm that the issue is gone and then plug your power cable back to your Mac